furnace whistling
new air ease natural gas furnace has a whistle. This did not happen with the old one. Two story house with two separate zones for heat and cool. Each level has their own thermostats. When cooling both zones at the same time no whistle. When cooling main floor level no whistling. When cooling upstairs it does whistle. Return air ducts clean. New air filter. Register's all open. Doors all open. Once had a humidifier but removed. Took tin off furnace duct work were humidifier was (return air before filter) no change. Whistle sounds like its coming from evaporator coil location. Removed tin on furnace duct just below coil and whistle stops. When furnace fan is running a large amount of air is coming out of this hole but no whistle. Coil looks very clean. Blew compressed air and no dust or debris. Home is 12 years old and cleaning duct work has been done 3 times by pros. No speed control as I would have lowered it to see if this would help. Thermostats have auto/on/ circular speed only. What am I missing?

New, so what did your installer say? They have better eyes on it than we do.
